# JQuery/AJAX PUT returning 400 error

Tags: jquery, ajax, express

I am attempting to update a file in my mongodb via a jquery ajax PUT that is taking data from a text area. I have been tinkering with this PUT for a while, adjusting the content-type, and have not gotten anywhere.

When i click the next button for the text area i want to PUT the input to my mongodb(via mongoose) but i keep receiving an error(in picture  below jquery/ajax code block). Could it be an issue with parsing?

### HTML

```
 <form name="answers" method="post"> 

 <textarea rows="30" cols="150" id="editor"></textarea>

     <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id='previous'>Previous</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id='next'>Next</button>
    </div>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn" id='submit'>Submit</button>

 </form>
```

### JQuery/AJAX POST

```
function answer() {
    var info = $('#editor').val()   // data from text area

    $.ajax({
            type: "PUT",
            url: "/tests/" + authCode,    // authCode-> global variable defined at top of page
            data: info,
            dataType: "json",                               
            contentType: "application/json",                                
            timeout: 5000,
            complete: function() {
              //called when complete
              console.log('process complete');
            },

            success: function(data) {
              console.log(data);
              console.log('process sucess');
           },

            error: function(err) {
                console.log(err);
              console.log('process error');
            },
        });
}
```

In the chrome console i receive the following error:
  [image]

### EXPRESS

```
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(express.static('files'));
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
extended: true
}));
```

...

```
app.put('/tests/:code', (req, res) => {
 res.set('Content-Type', 'html');
 console.log(req.body);    
});
```

req.body logs an empty object.

[network tab(dev console)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBi7e.png)

Comment: You should examine the Network tab in Chrome to see what body is being sent to the server. It looks like you aren't sending a valid JSON object to the server

Comment: @Christoph I looked into that and you are correct. I tried changing the data to - data: JSON.stringify(info), but i am still receiving the same error.

Comment: Can you post the body that's sent to the server? JSON has some stricter rules compared to simple JS objects for example

Comment: @Christoph i posted a pic at the bottom of my original post.

Comment: Ah, okay. What you are sending isn't a valid JSON object. Try it with something simple like: {"foo": 123}

Comment: @Christoph still not coming back right :(. Request payload from network tab now says:
foo=123

Console now says "Syntax error: unexpected token f"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A minimal and working example for sending a JSON object to a NodeJS Express server:

NodeJS

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json()); // to support JSON-encoded bodies

app.put("/", function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send("OK");
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

Frontend JS

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest;  
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
req.open('PUT', "/", true);  
req.send(JSON.stringify({foo:"bar"}));
```

You should try this example and then work towards your own use case step by step. For example first exchange this with your jQuery code and your HTML form. And after that modify the server code. Otherwise it will be hard for users here to help you with your scenario.

Answer (score -2):

It looks like you have an extra comma after you error statement.  It should look like:

```
function answer() {
var info = $('#editor').val()   // data from text area

$.ajax({
        type: "PUT",
        url: "/tests/" + authCode,    // authCode-> global variable defined at top of page
        data: info,
        dataType: "json",                               
        contentType: "application/json",                                
        timeout: 5000,
        complete: function() {
          //called when complete
          console.log('process complete');
        },

        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
          console.log('process sucess');
       },

        error: function(err) {
            console.log(err);
          console.log('process error');
        }
    });
```

}

Comment: Javascript allows an extra comma after the last element of an array or object. If this weren't allowed he would get a syntax error, not an error from the server.